# Do I need to pay a fee or a tax at the airport when I leave Malaysia to go to Australia?

Tags: air-travel, malaysia, taxes

Do I need to pay a fee or tax at the airport when leaving Malaysia to Australia?

Comment: Any fees or taxes that arise simply because you're travelling through the airport should be automatically included in the price of your ticket. What are the circumstances that make you thin that other fees or taxes would be payable?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Are you answering with regards to Malaysia? Because many airports collect fees separately. Even Vancouver did ~20 years ago. This is often due to complications where certain passengers, e.g. residents or certain visas, are exempt from departure taxes. And sometimes it [depends on the airline](https://costa-rica-guide.com/practical/documents-requirements/departure-tax/#include).

Comment: @user71659 Gosh, I never knew such a thing existed. What a mess.

Comment: @DavidRicherby even NZ airports did that a few years ago, an annoying $22-$25 as you left.  When I was in South America, Argentina at least was still doing it too :/

Comment: @DavidRicherby and in some cases, the departure tax could only be paid in cash using local currency. A big annoyance when you are in transit, as that means you must first withdraw or exchange cash before being able to pay it...

Answer (score 3):

**No**, Malaysia has no exit taxes and airport departure fees are already included in your plane ticket.